# How can I stucture my django code for a webpage with suppose 4 different divisions of data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am constructing a webpage in django which will parse data and show it all on a single webpage which is divided into 4 sections.

So, I need help in organizing the code so that the backend processing code for different sections can be kept seperate(maybe into seperate methods?), but everything needs to be called and rendered on a single request.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code to process date for each section is minimal, just put it all in the class or function for your view. If there is a lot of it, make a function for each section of data processing outside your view class or function, and just call that within your view so that your code stays readable. Regardless of which method you choose, remember to send the resulting data to your template as context, or to wherever you need it if Django is only your backend.

Comment: Yeah, I can do this. So the data that I receive will have to be then combined into a single context in the view function and then sent to a single template?

Comment: What do you mean by single context? Just put it all into a dictionary.

{&#39;data1&#39;: data1, &#39;data2&#39;: data2, &#39;data3&#39;: data3, &#39;data4&#39;: data4}

Then, put that dictionary as the context into your render function

Comment: I meant a single 'context' variable.
Understood. Thanks man, You really helped a lot.

Comment: Is your data for each section distinct? Context passed along to the render equation has to be a dictionary. You will then be able to access the values of this dictionary by using the corresponding keys as variables in your template.

Comment: The data is mostly distinct, though it is derived from the same queryset. Hence for that I have supplied that queryset to the init function of the class you mentioned. Then i will use that queryset in the separate functions. Would that be a good architecture?